# How to install matplotlib on portable python 3.10?

Tags: python

I have installed python 3.10 portable and I need to install libraries (matplotlib,....etc)
I am a beginner, how can I do that?

could you guide me on the steps, please?
here is the picture attached with all the exe files

I tried different methods but it still gives me errors regarding missing matplotlib

Comment: You did not post a picture of the exe files, please edit the question to include that.

Comment: @5rod Shouldn't be included as a picture, but as text. I'll tend to completely ignore questions with pictures

Comment: @SimonC, it is a little hard to include exe files as text, and easier as a picture, although if possible, I agree with you that the OP should try to include it as text. You shouldn't just ignore questions with pictures, instead, if possible, it is better to try to edit them.